# Entity Framework - switch from one-to-many to many-to-many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 models which you can see below called ProductModel, ProductsModel and CategoryModel.  Currently, many products can be in one and only one category.  But I need to switch it so that products can be in more than one category.  How do I do that?

CategoryModel:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String categoryName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String categoryDBName { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

}
```

ProductModel:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Index("ItemNumber", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
    public String imageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PDF Name")]
    public String PDFName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryModel Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public virtual BrochureModel Brochure { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrochureList { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCategories(int id = 0)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Value = cat.ID.ToString(), Text = cat.categoryName };

                if (id > 0 && cat.ID == id)
                {
                    sli.Selected = true;
                }
                list.Add(sli);
            }
            return list;
        }

    }

    public ProductModel()
    {
        active = true;
    }

}
```

ProductsModel:

```
public class ProductsModel
{
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    public bool hasFrozen { get; set; }

    public static List<ProductModel> getProductsByCat(string category)
    {

        return ProductsModelDB.getProductsByCat(category);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to migrate an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get there. Looks like your using annotations (vs fluent api) so you could add collections on each side or create a bridge class (ProductCategory).

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String categoryName { get; set; }

    ...

    public IEnumerable<ProductModel> ProductList { get; set; }

}

public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...

    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

Personally, I prefer the nice fluent api for this.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductModel>() 
    .HasMany(t => t.CategoryList) 
    .WithMany(t => t.ProductList) 
    .Map(m => 
    { 
        m.ToTable("ProductCategory"); 
        m.MapLeftKey("ProductID"); 
        m.MapRightKey("CategoryID"); 
    });
```

Comment: I'm finally getting around to working on this now.  I added the ProductList and the CategoryList.  Then I stuck in the last block of code into the ProductContext.  On the line `.HasMany(t => t.CategoryList)` I get the error: `The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Models.ProductModel>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Models.ProductModel,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TTargetEntity>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: You may not need the fluent part. EF can figure a lot of it out by convention.

Comment: OK, I was able to fix that error.  Now I still can't get it to create that table.  Do I need to create the bridge class for it to create the new table?

Comment: Should be automatic. You using migrations? You can inspect the Up() code.

Comment: Yes I am.  When I run `add-migration Initial`, my Up() code is blank.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do I need to create the ProductCategory model?  What all goes inside that?

Comment: Nevermind, those questions.  I figured it out.  Now I'm getting another error of which I posted a new question on SO.